# 301 Redirect, but exclude namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, apache, redirect

**BACKGROUND**:
I have a Rails app where my home page is products/index.

I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file to redirect requests from products/ to root.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*products\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)products /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is working great. Requests to /products are redirecting to root, and requests to products/[id] are still routing to products/id as I would want.

**PROBLEM**:
The only problem is that I have an admin section with the namespace /admin.  And in that admin section, I have /products.
So now when my admin user is in the admin section of the site and he clicks on the "products" link, he should be routed to url/admin/products.  However, the rewrite rule is redirecting him to url/admin

**QUESTION**
How do I exclude the admin prefix from the redirect code I listed above?

I imagine that somewhere in the regex I should be able to add something like: [^admin] 
But I can't get anything to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another rewrite condition like this to start off:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin`

This will disable the following rewrite rules for any request starting with admin.

Comment: That was almost it.  It just needed a small tweak: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)admin

Comment: Your tweak makes that a self-defeating mass of expressions. The '^' character in this context is to match from the beginning of the line. Your tweak now matches the beginning of the line then any number of random characters. If your admin is that at start of the URL, either match what IS at the beginning or just drop the '^' and match anywhere in the request. In other words `^(.*)` is exactly equivolent to nothing at all.